# What do you call A of a relation R in AxB?

Tags: terminology

Given a relation $ R \subseteq A \times B $.

from wikipedia: The **domain** of R is the set of all x such that xRy for at least one y. The **range** of R is the set of all y such that xRy for at least one x.

Hence: $domain \subseteq A, range \subseteq B$

A cannot be called domain, since that name is taken by one of its subsets which is only equal to it in special cases. If you insist on calling A the domain then my new question is: what is the set of all x such that xRy for at least one y is called?

Wikipedia mentions "set of departure" for A and "set of destination" for B. But I am wondering if people would understand and accept if I would use those terms.

Comment: In Nicolas Bourbaki, [Elements of Mathematics: Theory of sets](https://books.google.it/books?id=IL-SI67hjI4C&pg=PA76) (Engl.transl. 1968) we can find : "A *correspondence* between a set $A$ and a set $B$ is a triple $\Gamma = \langle G, A, B \rangle$ where $G$ is a *graph* such that $pr_1 G \subset A$ and $pr_2 G \subset B$. $G$ is said the *graph* of $\Gamma$, $A$ is the *source*, and $B$ is the *target* of $\Gamma$."

Comment: A *graph* is a set of ordered pairs and $pr_1 G = \{ x \mid (\exists y) (x,y) \in G \}$ is the *domain* of $G$ (and the same for $pr_2 G$, the *range* of $G$).

Comment: You can see also this related post : [unambiguous-terminology-for-domains-ranges-sources-and-targets](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446551/unambiguous-terminology-for-domains-ranges-sources-and-targets).